# JavaScript Iframes combined with three.js unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, three.js

http://pastebin.com/38dGR6iF
http://pastebin.com/M03PdUfT
I am trying to divide my browser webpage into 2 parts, one which will contain a form and one which will contain Three.js code. "form.html" is an empty html file with background set to black. The second pastebin file is a Three.js code I got for a Three.js book I read. That's the standalone code, it works. I tried implementing this code ( and as such just copy pasting it ) in my first pastebin file.

In the first pastebin file I have an iframe which points to the form.html. The rest of the body is implementing the Three.js code. What I would want to see when I open my file is the iframe to be completely black ( since the form.html webfile is completely black ) and the Three.js loaded in what it is left of the body. My Three.js is not showing up though. Where is my mistake ? Thank you for your time.